# Skip/pass non-standard prolog code

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, erlog

I'm developing under SWI-Prolog, but my target is Erlog (https://github.com/rvirding/erlog). I need a way to use non-standard Prolog syntax.
Is there a way to write prolog code that will be disregarded by the SWI-compiler i.e. make it invisible.

Here is example how does it look like :

```
do_stuff(G,Amt) :- ecall(erlog_demo:efunc('Elixir.Blah':stuff({G,Amt})).
```

I was thinking if there is a way for SWI to skip that and I have another declaration that does nothing.

```
do_stuff(_,_).
```

One option probably is to comment it and then use parser to remove the comment before running in Erlog, but this seem cumbersome.

Any other ideas.

======

```
is_dialect(swi) :- catch(current_prolog_flag(dialect, swi), _, fail).
:- if(is_dialect(swi)).
    do_stuff(_,_).
:- else.
   do_stuff(G,Amt) :- ecall(erlog_demo:efunc('Elixir.Blah':stuff({G,Amt})).
:- endif.
```

Syntax error: Operator expected

Comment: I find your problem description quite puzzling. What do you want to achieve? Is it "how to do Prolog processor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this idiom to keep code running in different implementations

```
:- if(swi).

 gen_hash_lin_probe(Key, HashTable, Value) :-
    arg(_, HashTable, E),
    nonvar(E),
    E = Key-Value.

:- elif(yap).

 gen_hash_lin_probe(Key, HashTable, Value) :-
    HashTable =.. [htlp|Args],
    nth1(_, Args, E),
    nonvar(E),
    E = Key-Value.

:- endif.
```

where predicates swi/0 or yap/0 are imported from this module(prolog_impl)

```
:- module(prolog_impl, [swi/0, yap/0, prolog_impl/1]).

swi :- prolog_impl(swi).
yap :- prolog_impl(yap).

prolog_impl(K) :-
    F =.. [K,_,_,_,_],
    current_prolog_flag(version_data, F).
```

Comment: You can simplify your code by using the de facto standard `dialect` Prolog flag.

Comment: @PauloMoura: thanks. Your suggestion will be useful to OP also

Comment: tried it, but still getting "Syntax error: Operator expected", probably because this is foreign syntax to prolog !!!

Comment: This only works as long as the syntax is roughly the same.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based, in part, on 
[@Capelli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33058810/4609915) and your comments on his candidate solution.

We propose a different way. *Follow the dots* step-by-step...

- For a start, we take the following simplified and shortened snippet.

  ```
  :- if(true).       p(3).
  :- elif(false).    p(4+3).
  :- endif.
  ```
- In above sample we can see that the "else" branch is never taken, ever.
  So... could we, in principle, put arbitrary text and binary data there?

  ```
  :- if(true).       p(3).
  :- elif(false).    p (4);;[ p())
  :- endif.
  ```

  нет! Upon (re-)loading, we get: **⚠ Syntax error: Operator expected**

  TIL that all sections between `elif` and `endif` must be valid Prolog text.
- Let's try something different which was inspired by that phrases you used, in particular: "[...] use non-standard Prolog syntax [...] code that will be disregarded [...] make it invisible [...]"

  To me, the phrase "non-standard syntax" indicates that new operator(s) might be introduced (or old ones redefined):

  ```
  :- op(500,xfx,=>).

  :- if(true).       p(2).
  :- elif(false).    p(3 => 3).
  :- endif.
  ```

  Consider the following variation:

  ```
  :- if(true).       p(2).
  :- elif(false).    :- op(500,xfx,=>).   % is moving the `op/3` here ok?
                     p(3 => 3).
  :- endif.
  ```

  нет! Upon (re-)loading, we get: **⚠ Unterminated conditional compilation from [...]**

---

There is another way! We can proceed by inserting a special-purpose `end_of_file` fact to tell the Prolog text reader to disregard everything after `end_of_file.`

We use it like this:

```
% snip_at_end.pl
xxx1.

xxx2.

end_of_file.

xxx3.

:- op (500, xfx,eat).       % broken syntax (pt.1)
1 ]][[ v                    % broken syntax (pt.2)
```

Simple test using SICStus Prolog:

```
$ sicstus
SICStus 4.3.2 (x86_64-linux-glibc2.12): Fri May  8 01:05:09 PDT 2015
[... License information ...]
| ?- compile(snip_at_end).
% compiling /home/stefan/prolog/snip_at_end.pl...
% compiled /home/stefan/prolog/snip_at_end.pl in module user, 40 msec 400672 bytes
yes
| ?- xxx1.
yes
| ?- xxx2.
yes
| ?- xxx3.
! Existence error in user:xxx3/0
! procedure user:xxx3/0 does not exist
! goal:  user:xxx3
```

Hope this helps! I'm curious / interested if my answer fits your problem:)

Comment: Every day should have at least one TIL moment.

Answer (score 3):

One closing parenthesis is missing in the "else" branch.

```
do_stuff(G,Amt) :- ecall(erlog_demo:efunc('Elixir.Blah':stuff({G,Amt})).  % BAD
do_stuff(G,Amt) :- ecall(erlog_demo:efunc('Elixir.Blah':stuff({G,Amt}))). % OK!
```

Simply count the number of opening parentheses. When `.` (period, full-step) is reached the difference count of opening vs closing must amount to exactly zero.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Every mistake is trivial and obvious, **once** it"s understood and visible:)  Build up your toolbox with a sign "Prolog" on it. Get to know tricks, hacks, tools, etc. Why not use an editor with suitable  extentions?